# Certain folders on a shared network drive are getting the hidden attribute at random times

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders, network-drive

One of our shared network drives has a few folders that at random times get the hidden attribute making it look like the folders have dissapeared for the regular users.

Share resides on a Windows 2008 R2 server, all clients are Windows 7.

Antivirus is being kept up to date.

Is there any way how to track from where is the hidden attribute being set ?

Answer (score 0):

If the date-time of the folder changes when the attribute does, you might monitor what process was running then.

A free tool to monitor folders is [Folder Changes View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html) from Nirsoft. Though it records, "every filename that is being modified, created, or deleted while the folder is being monitored", I do not know if it will trap an attribute change.

If *Folder Changes View* is not sufficient, MS does provide the [Sync Framework 2.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902836%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) that could be used to create a small application to monitor the folder.

Comment: The date-time stays the same after each hidden episode. For the most part, folders were created by server local admin account. This should prevent certain changes to the folders from users that don't have modify or full access for it's permissions. Tried _Folder Changes View_ but it does not record the attribute change unfortunately.